# How do I check if more than one key is being pushed at a time?

Tags: python, windows

I am creating a keylogger to monitor my PC and I want to have a key combination that shuts the keylogger off or turns on the user interface, not sure yet. But the problem is that I can't figure out how to check if two or three buttons are being pressed at the same time ? How do I do that ?
Here's my source so far :
http://paste.pocoo.org/show/232233/

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get a keyup/keydown event, rather than a keypress event.

Then all you do is keep a list of buttons that are down, and remove the button when keyup is called.

Answer (score 0):

Use GetKeyState to see if another key is pressed. Try this to quit when ctrl-shift-q is pressed:

```
import win32con

def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    if event.Ascii == 81 and
        win32api.GetKeyState(win32con.VK_CONTROL) & 0x8000 and
        win32api.GetKeyState(win32con.VK_SHIFT) & 0x8000:
        LogFile.close()
        exit()
    LogFile.write(str(event.Key))

return True
```